# Deconvolution with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Is there a way of doing deconvolution with OpenCV?

I'm just impressed by the improvement shown here

[image: from https://web.archive.org/web/20160402174700/http://www.olympusmicro.com/primer/digitalimaging/deconvolution/images/deconalgorithmsfigure1.jpg]

and would like to add this feature also to my software.

**EDIT** (Additional information for bounty.)

I still have not figured out how to implement the deconvolution.
This code helps me to sharpen the image, but I think the deconvolution could do it better.

```
void ImageProcessing::sharpen(QImage & img)
{
    IplImage* cvimg = createGreyFromQImage( img );
    if ( !cvimg ) return;

    IplImage* gsimg = cvCloneImage(cvimg );
    IplImage* dimg = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(cvimg), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    IplImage* outgreen = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(cvimg), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
    IplImage* zeroChan = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(cvimg), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvZero(zeroChan);

    cv::Mat smat( gsimg, false );
    cv::Mat dmat( dimg, false );

    cv::GaussianBlur(smat, dmat, cv::Size(0, 0), 3);
    cv::addWeighted(smat, 1.5, dmat, -0.5 ,0, dmat);
    cvMerge( zeroChan, dimg, zeroChan, NULL, outgreen);

    img = IplImage2QImage( outgreen );
    cvReleaseImage( &gsimg );
    cvReleaseImage( &cvimg );
    cvReleaseImage( &dimg );
    cvReleaseImage( &outgreen );
    cvReleaseImage( &zeroChan );
}
```

Hoping for helpful hints!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: Found an interesting article on the topic: http://yuzhikov.com/articles/BlurredImagesRestoration1.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can write a deconvolution Code using OpenCV. But there are no ready to use Functions (yet).

To get started you can look at [this Example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/deconvolution.py) that shows the implementation of Wiener Deconvolution in Python using OpenCV.

Here is [another Example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/theTechTrek/entry/experiments_with_deblurring_using_opencv1?lang=en) using C, but this is from 2012, so maybe it is outdated.

Comment: Thank you. It looks much more complicated than I've expected. The second example is straightforward, should be possible to understand and rewrite it in OpenCV2. I'll wait some time for another proposals (possibly other methods such as nearest neighbour deconvolution) and select yours, if nothing else comes.

Comment: finally I've learned as much of python as sufficient for running the first example. The result on car-images is astonishing. I believe it would be even possible to determine the psf from the motion analysis (small lines all in same direction) having some context information of the image. However on my images (cells in microscope) the result were not as good. Possibly I haven't configured PFS properly and it is not that obvious to do as in car example.

Comment: It is crucial to know your PSF, without knowing your PSF deconvolution is a very hard task (as youhave to guess it). Maybe people can help you if you describe your setup for taking the images in detail.

Comment: OK, I will add the info. Actually, my direction is Z. This possibly means, PSF can't be defined from one image but from a stack of captured images while moving microscope up and down at the same position. I think this is not clear from by current question description.

Answer (score 6):

Nearest neighbor deconvolution is a technique which is used typically on a stack of images in the Z plane in optical microscopy.  This review paper: Jean-Baptiste Sibarita. *[Deconvolution Microscopy](http://www2.ujf-grenoble.fr/medecine/iab/clientzone/plforme9/fichiers/DeconvolutionMicroscopy_Sibarita_Springer.pdf)*. Adv Biochem Engin/Biotechnol (2005) 95: 201–243 covers quite a lot of the techniques used, including the one you are interested in.  This is also a nice intro: http://blogs.fe.up.pt/BioinformaticsTools/microscopy/

This numpy+scipy python example shows how it works:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage

width = 100
height = 100
depth = 10
imgs = zeros((height, width, depth))

# prepare test input, a stack of images which is zero except for a point which has been blurred by a 3D gaussian
#sigma = 3
#imgs[height/2,width/2,depth/2] = 1
#imgs = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(imgs, sigma)

# read real input from stack of images img_0000.png, img_0001.png, ... (total number = depth)
# these must have the same dimensions equal to width x height above
# if imread reads them as having more than one channel, they need to be converted to one channel
for k in range(depth):
    imgs[:,:,k] = scipy.ndimage.imread( "img_%04d.png" % (k) )

# prepare output array, top and bottom image in stack don't get filtered
out_imgs = zeros_like(imgs)
out_imgs[:,:,0] = imgs[:,:,0]
out_imgs[:,:,-1] = imgs[:,:,-1]

# apply nearest neighbor deconvolution
alpha = 0.4 # adjustabe parameter, strength of filter
sigma_estimate = 3 # estimate, just happens to be same as the actual

for k in range(1, depth-1):
    # subtract blurred neighboring planes in the stack from current plane
    # doesn't have to be gaussian, any other kind of blur may be used: this should approximate PSF
    out_imgs[:,:,k] = (1+alpha) * imgs[:,:,k]  \
        - (alpha/2) * scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(imgs[:,:,k-1], sigma_estimate) \
        - (alpha/2) * scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(imgs[:,:,k+1], sigma_estimate)

# show result, original on left, filtered on right
compare_img = copy(out_imgs[:,:,depth/2])
compare_img[:,:width/2] = imgs[:,:width/2,depth/2]
imshow(compare_img)
show()
```

Comment: That's cool! Thaks for the links! I'll read the links next days, test the code and most probably give you the bounty. P.S.: meanwhile I considering to embed Python in my application or moving all image processing functions to a separate process implemented in python. So many powerful packages out there...

Comment: Sorry, I've just started learning python. Could you help testing the code with real images? I've tried img = scipy.ndimage.imread( "19756782_g.png") where png is a grey 8-bit image. Then I put such images in the set/(array?) imgs.  Unfortunatelly I get error " 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape' " in the loop for k in range(1, imgs.shape[2]-1).

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: Does this sample work for you?  Please see updated code above, and let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: "Then I put such images in the set/(array?) imgs" - *imgs* it is an numpy array (ndarray), a complete stack of images in one binary structure (so it's 3D, width x height x depth).  There is no convenient way to append to it :)  But see above for how to read it in from separate image files.

Comment: And the winner of the bounty is ...:-) Seriously, thank you for the link and the code example. My problem is still not solved as I wanted, but I got some clarity now. I have to go for PSF and reduce shaking while capturing images in Z-direction. Once I've found out how to do it in OpenCV, I'll post the example.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Have you been able to implement this in OpenCV? either the determining of the PSF or the Wiener Deconvolution?

Comment: @salgarcia: Not till now. There are some implementation details of my microscope Z-positioning/focusing/callibration algorithm, which doesn't allow me to apply deconvolution in the praxis. I've postponed this feature to the next relaunch. Actually, Wiener Deconvolution works fine in python-examples of opencv2 as mentioned by Mailerdaimon.

Comment: @AlexI The links both you shared not available anymore, can you please edit the links if possible? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The sample image you provided actually is a very good example of Lucy-Richardson deconvolution. There is not a built-in function in OpenCV libraries for this deconvolution method. In Matlab, you may use the deconvolution with "deconvlucy.m" function. Actually, you can see the source code for some of the functions in Matlab by typing "open " or "edit ". 
Below, I tried to simplify the Matlab code in **OpenCV**.

```
// Lucy-Richardson Deconvolution Function
// input-1 img: NxM matrix image
// input-2 num_iterations: number of iterations
// input-3 sigma: sigma of point spread function (PSF)
// output result: deconvolution result

// Window size of PSF
int winSize = 10 * sigmaG + 1 ;

// Initializations
Mat Y = img.clone();
Mat J1 = img.clone();
Mat J2 = img.clone();
Mat wI = img.clone(); 
Mat imR = img.clone();  
Mat reBlurred = img.clone();    

Mat T1, T2, tmpMat1, tmpMat2;
T1 = Mat(img.rows,img.cols, CV_64F, 0.0);
T2 = Mat(img.rows,img.cols, CV_64F, 0.0);

// Lucy-Rich. Deconvolution CORE

double lambda = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < num_iterations; j++) 
{       
    if (j>1) {
        // calculation of lambda
        multiply(T1, T2, tmpMat1);
        multiply(T2, T2, tmpMat2);
        lambda=sum(tmpMat1)[0] / (sum( tmpMat2)[0]+EPSILON);
        // calculation of lambda
    }

    Y = J1 + lambda * (J1-J2);
    Y.setTo(0, Y < 0);

    // 1)
    GaussianBlur( Y, reBlurred, Size(winSize,winSize), sigmaG, sigmaG );//applying Gaussian filter 
    reBlurred.setTo(EPSILON , reBlurred <= 0); 

    // 2)
    divide(wI, reBlurred, imR);
    imR = imR + EPSILON;

    // 3)
    GaussianBlur( imR, imR, Size(winSize,winSize), sigmaG, sigmaG );//applying Gaussian filter 

    // 4)
    J2 = J1.clone();
    multiply(Y, imR, J1);

    T2 = T1.clone();
    T1 = J1 - Y;
}

// output
result = J1.clone();
```

Here are some examples and results.

[image]
[image]

[Example results with Lucy-Richardson deconvolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGALP.png)

Visit my blog [Here](https://onsignalandimageprocessing.blogspot.com.tr/2017/02/lucy-richardson-deconvolution.html) where you may access the whole code.

Comment: Nice blog you have there!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you understand what deconvolution is. The idea behind deconvolution is to remove the detector response from the image. This is commonly done in astronomy.

For instance, if you have a CCD mounted to a telescope, then any image you take is a convolution of what you are looking at in the sky and the response of the optical system. The telescope (or camera lens or whatever) will have some point spread function (PSF). That is, if you look at a point source that is very far away, like a star, when you take an image of it, the star will be blurred over several pixels. This blurring -- the point spread -- is what you would like to remove. If you know the point spread function of your optical system very well, then you can deconvolve the PSF from your image and obtain a sharper image.

Unless you happen to know the PSF of your optics (nontrivial to measure!), you should seek out some other option for sharpening your image. I doubt OpenCV has anything like a Richardson-Lucy algorithm built-in.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning  Richardson-Lucy algorithm. Meanwhile I have understood the deconvolution more or less the way you've described. Unfortunately the example posted by Alex I doesn't work on my images, as my PSF is not Gaussian blurring. I've also came across PSF as I tried to test my auto-focus algorithm using a stack of images unsharpened with blurring. It didn't work and someone on SO pointed me to "PSF".

Comment: If you want to use deconvolution, you need to measure the PSF of your optics. I suppose you could guess at it, but you would be fumbling in the dark. To measure it, you need to image a point source of white light at various points in the field of view. Optical PSFs are often approximated as Gaussians, but you'd at least need to know the width of your distribution. Really, unless you are willing to measure your PSF, I would highly suggest you look for another sharpening algorithm.